# Blocking nslookup on A record

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

Need to know which port to be blocked in my local machine so that the nslookup on A record doesnot work?
To know the above i need to understand how the lookup on A record how does the request go from the local machine (port) to the nameservers/ rootservers?

For example:
C:> nslookup -type=a google.com

Server:  MyDslModem.local.lan
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google.com
Address:  209.85.231.104

Here which from which local port from the local machine does the lookup starts from?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? Do you want the A record for your machine to not be resolved by your DNS server? Do you want to block outbound DNS queries so that nslookup doesn't work? Do you want your DNS server to not answer DNS queries?

Comment: The question is the second one : " Do you want to block outbound DNS queries so that nslookup doesn't work?"

Comment: My Main intention is to check how all the dns look up on A record would fail in a network. Reason i am needing the info is to setup a domain lookup to verify if the domain in the email address entered is valid. Sorry if my question confounds you!!

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a better answer if you tell us why you'd want to do this.

DNS traffic uses UDP port 53, but if you want to block that, why not just remove the DNS server configuration from your network adapter?

Comment: My Main intention is to check how all the dns look up on A record would fail in a network. Reason i am needing the info is to setup a domain lookup to verify if the domain in the email address entered is valid.

Comment: @msher420 You can just look up the TLD `invalid` or any subdomain thereof. These return NXDOMAIN on the global Internet. See RFC 6761.

Answer (score 0):

Outgoing network requests are dynamic and network address translation on your router will use the available high ports. When it leaves your network (192.168.1.0/24) your router will use NAT to assign an available dynamic port to service the outgoing request.

That aside, if you want to prevent a host record lookup from succeeding you can either just put a false record and ip address in your local host file or map it to a false address on your local DNS server before it gets forwarded out.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the local hosts file to point specific names to 127.0.0.1 to prevent access.

This works because (in most cases) the lookup will check the local hosts file before the DNS servers - and if a value is returned it won't look any further.

However, verifying this using nslookup on Windows won't work, as nslookup queries the nameserver (hence the name).  You can check using ping on the hostname - ping does a normal lookup.